# jQuery 3D Touch Menu - Unable to 'select' Links by Dragging Finger Over It

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I recently finished making a jQuery 3D Touch menu for iOS devices with 3D Touch support. Normally when you 3D Touch on an icon in iOS, you can select a "link" just by dragging your finger to that link without having to lift your finger. How would I accomplish this in jQuery?

```
$('body').append(
    '<div id="force-touch-popup">' +
        '<a href="/" class="force-touch-link ft-top ft-1">' +
            '<i class="forceTouchIcon fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
            '<i class="forceTouchText">Home</i>' +
        '</a>' +
        '<a href="/about" target="_popup" class="force-touch-link ft-middle ft-2">' +
            '<i class="forceTouchIcon fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
            '<i class="forceTouchText">About Us</i>' +
        '</a>' +
        '<a href="cydia://url/https://cydia.saurik.com/api/share#?source=http://repo.[MY SITE].com/" target="_blank" class="force-touch-link ft-middle ft-3">' +
            '<i class="forceTouchIcon fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
            '<i class="forceTouchText">Add To Cydia</i>' +
        '</a>' +
        '<a href="cydia://url/http://repo.[MY SITE].com/" target="_blank" class="force-touch-link ft-bottom ft-4">' +
            '<i class="forceTouchIcon fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
            '<i class="forceTouchText">Open In Cydia</i>' +
        '</a>' +
    '</div>'
);
```

[Current menu (if you need any other code, let me know)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBDOb.jpg)

Comment: needs way more jquery